# Making AES Encryption in Swift similar to Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

Encryption of password generated in Android app and Java back end are same however in iOS I have tried using CryptoSwift and CommonCrypto and other code available but didn't get desired output matching with other two and hence posting the question. Please let me know any similar counter code/class is there in iOS for generating same output or Let me know whats missing in my code. Thanks in advance.

Here is Android Code

```
private static byte[] salt = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
private static final Integer ITERATRION_COUNT = 65536;
private  static final Integer KEY_LENGTH = 256;

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String password) throws Exception {
    
    String encryptedText = null;
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATRION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            encryptedText= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return encryptedText;
}
```

I also took help from ChatGPT but the code converted encrypted string is only half matched.

iOS Code –

```
func encryptString(strToEncrypt: String, password: String) -> String? {
    let salt: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    let saltData = Data(salt)
    let passwordData = password.data(using: .utf8)!
    
    // Key derivation using PBKDF2
    var key = Data(repeating: 0, count: kCCKeySizeAES256)
    let keyLength = key.count
    let keyDerivationResult = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { keyBytes in
        
        saltData.withUnsafeBytes { saltBytes in
            CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(
                CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
                password, passwordData.count,
                saltBytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), saltData.count,
                CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256),
                65536, // rounds
                keyBytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), keyLength
            )
        }
    }
    
    guard keyDerivationResult == kCCSuccess else { return nil }
    
    // Encryption
    
    guard let dataToEncrypt = strToEncrypt.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    
    let algorithm = CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES)
    let options = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    var numBytesEncrypted = 0
    var encryptedData = Data(count: dataToEncrypt.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    
    let encryptedDataLength = encryptedData.count
    
    let cryptStatus = encryptedData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { encryptedBytes in
        dataToEncrypt.withUnsafeBytes { dataToEncryptBytes in
            key.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt), algorithm, options,
                        keyBytes.baseAddress, key.count, nil,
                        dataToEncryptBytes.baseAddress, dataToEncrypt.count,
                        encryptedBytes.baseAddress, encryptedDataLength,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }
    
    guard cryptStatus == kCCSuccess else { return nil }
    
    encryptedData.removeSubrange(numBytesEncrypted..<encryptedData.count)
    
    // Convert to Base64
    return encryptedData.base64EncodedString()
}
```

> The expected result is:
>
> Uname / Pwd:    leahsklar@earthlink.net / test123
>
> {"username":"EwYSS++oSbP1Kj7dPjd9wAqVK4FRvxfte29eUVRyzGI=","password":"jUJ/qlcGOOz/9USYQKNnOQ==","isDebug":true}}

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is using `.utf32` to get the password data. Have you tried `.utf8'?

Comment: The same applies to the plaintext, it must be `strToEncrypt.data(using: .utf8)`. In addition, probably ECB must be specified: `CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode)` (since no mode is specified in the Java code, the provider-dependent default value is used; for the SunJCE provider this is ECB). Note that ECB is insecure.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes initially used .utf8 but when it didn't work tried with .utf16 and .utf32 as well. corrected the code

Comment: Works for me with the changes! At least with my own test data. I can't figure out from yours, what should the ciphertext be, `EwYSS...`? or `jUJ/...`? Neither of them is generated with the Java code when `leahsklar@earthlink.net` is used as plaintext and `test123` as password. Please explain how this test data is to be understood.